# SQL Query - Combining Two tables, removing duplicates and only keeping most recent by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to throw a query together within SQLServer Management Studio 2008, I'm joining the two tables via 'tax_id' but I have a duplicate entry from table 2 (Tax_Rate_Table)  where I need to ONLY display one entry with the most recent 'effective_date' as you can see below, Tax_ID 4 has a duplicate entry:

```
1.TAX_TABLE---------    
tax_id  description

        1   AZ State
        2   AZ-Maricopa Co
        4   AZ-Maricopa/Mesa



2.Tax_RATE_TABLE-------
tax_id  effective_date  tax_percent

1   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 5.6
2   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 0.7
4   2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 1.75
4   2019-03-01 00:00:00.000 2
```

My joining and descending by effective date works, however, I'm trying to utilize "order by effective_date desc LIMIT 1;" But the Limit function does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses a lateral join (not that SQL Server does not support the `limit` syntax, but uses `top` instead):

```
select t.*, tr.effective_date, tr.tax_percent
from tax_table t
cross apply (
    select top (1) *
    from tax_rate_table tr
    where tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
    order by tr.effective_date desc
) tr
```

You can also join and filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*, tr.effective_date, tr.tax_percent
from tax_table t
inner join tax_rate_table tr on tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
where tr.effective_date = (
    select max(tr1.effective_date)
    from tax_rate_table tr1
    where tr1.tax_id = tr.tax_id
)
```

Or you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        tr.effective_date, 
        tr.tax_percent,
        row_number() over(partition by t.tax_id order by tr.effective_date desc) rn
    from tax_table t
    inner join tax_rate_table tr on tr.tax_id = t.tax_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, working with strict deadlines here and SQL isn't quite my expertise within this project! I utilized the correlated subquery method to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with rates
AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tax_id ORDER BY effective_date desc) as pID
    FROM tax_table t
        inner join tax_rate_table r on t.ID = r.tax_id
)

select
    tax_id
    ,DESCRIPTION
    ,effective_date
    ,percentage
FROM rates
WHERE pid = 1
```